# How to find which URI has each shiny app tab

Tags: r, google-analytics, shiny

I have a shiny app with several tabs and I want to explore users' behavior and pageviews using Google Analytics. Currently I have the statistics for each page in Google Analytics. But shiny app doesn't have different URLs for different tabs. So, when I add URl to the end of URL (/p/####/) I see that the page doesn't exist.

[print screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyFYu.png)

[print screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qThQJ.png)

How is it possible to find out to which tab belongs which URI?